# limit when n->infinity from (1+1/2n)*(1+1/(2n+2))*(1+1/(2n+4))*...*(1+1/(2n+2n))

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{2n})(1+\frac{1}{2n+2})(1+\frac{1}{2n+4}) \cdots (1+\frac{1}{2n+2n})$

if we note that limit with $r$ than we have:
$$\ln\left((1+\frac{1}{2n})(1+\frac{1}{2n+2})(1+\frac{1}{2n+4}) \cdots (1+\frac{1}{2n+2n})\right)=\ln(r)$$
$$=>ln(1+\frac{1}{2n})+...+\ln(1+\frac{1}{2n+2n})=ln(r)$$ but from here i dont know. I know $e^{1/4}<r<e^{1/2}$ because $(1+\frac{1}{2n})^n>r>(1+\frac{1}{2n+2n})^n$ 
or write limit in this form

$$\frac{(2n+1)(2n+3)...(2n+2n+1)}{2^{n+1}n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)}
=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+3)...(2n+2n+1)(n-1)!}{2^{n+1}2n!}$$

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is unreadable.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on formatting for this site.  Please use it to re-format your question.

Comment: @lulu lol laughed so hard at that

Comment: This is not unreadable, and there's no need to take such a scolding tone with the OP.

Comment: I believe the answer is $\sqrt{2}$. See my answer. Perhaps there is a shorter way to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer is $\sqrt{2}$. If that's wrong, I shall delete it immediately.

\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=0}^n \bigg( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+2k} \bigg) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\bigg(\ln \bigg( \prod_{k=0}^n \bigg( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+2k} \bigg) \bigg) \bigg)\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^n\ln\bigg( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+2k} \bigg) \bigg) \end{align}
And I will prove that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n\bigg[\ln\bigg( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+2k} \bigg)-\frac{1}{2n+2k}\bigg]= 0$$
But
\begin{align} \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2n+2k} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)=\ln(\sqrt{2})\end{align}
So that we have
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n\ln\bigg( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+2k} \bigg)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2n+2k}=\ln(\sqrt{2}) $$
So that by continuity of $\exp$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=0}^n \bigg( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+2k} \bigg)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^n\ln\bigg( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+2k} \bigg) \bigg) \bigg) = \exp(\ln(\sqrt{2}))=\color{red}{\sqrt{2}}$$

---

> We go back and prove that
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n\bigg[\ln\bigg( 1+ \frac{1}{2n+2k} \bigg)-\frac{1}{2n+2k}\bigg]= 0$$

$$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots = x + \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m+1}x^{m+2}}{m+2} $$
, for all $|x| < 1$. So that
$$\ln(1+x) - x = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m+1}x^{m+2}}{m+2}= x^2 \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m+1}x^{m}}{m+2} $$
Let $g(x) = \sum \frac{(-1)^{m+1}x^{m}}{m+2}$. For $g$ is continuous, it is bounded on any closed interval in $(-1,1)$. Let $C>0$ such that for all $x \in [0, 0.5]$, $|g(x)| < C$.

Now $\ln(1+x)-x = x^2g(x)$. Put $x_{n,k} = \frac{1}{2n+2k}$. And we wish to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n x_{n,k}^2 g(x_{n,k}) = 0$. However, for all $n > 1$ and $k \geq 0$, $0< x_{n,k} < 1/2$. So that $|x_{n,k}^2 g(x_{n,k})|\leq C|x_{n,k}^2|=Cx_{n,k}^2$. Therefore, it suffices to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n x_{n,k}^2$ converges to $0$. But

\begin{align} \sum_{k = 0}^n x_{n,k}^2 = \sum_{k = 0}^n \bigg( \frac{1}{2n( 1 + \frac{k}{n})}\bigg)^2 = \frac{1}{4n} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 0}^n \bigg( \frac{1}{1 + \frac{k}{n}}\bigg)^2 \end{align}
and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^n \bigg( \frac{1}{1 + \frac{k}{n}}\bigg)^2 = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{-1}{1+x}\bigg|_0^1 = \frac{1}{2}$$
Therefore, there is $N\in \Bbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall\ n \geq N$,

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^n \bigg( \frac{1}{1 + \frac{k}{n}}\bigg)^2< 1 \implies 0 \leq \sum_{k = 0}^n x_{n,k}^2  < \frac{1}{4n} \to 0$$

---

**Another way**

As suggested by the OP, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/x = 1$ is sufficient for $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \bigg[f\bigg(\frac{1}{2n+2k} \bigg)-\frac{1}{2n+2k}\bigg] = 0$$

We write 
$$E(x) = \frac{f(x) - x}{x}, \quad x_{n,k} = \frac{1}{2n+2k} $$
Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. By assumption, $\lim_{x \to 0} E(x) =0$. Choose $\delta>0$ s.t. $0<x < \delta \implies |E(x)| < \epsilon$.

Choose $N_1 \in \Bbb{N}$ s.t. $\frac{1}{2N_1} < \delta$. For all $n \geq N_1$ and $k \in \Bbb{N}$, $x_{n,k} 
 = \frac{1}{2n+2k}\leq \frac{1}{2N_1} < \delta$.

$$|f(x_{n,k})-x_{n,k}| = |E(x_{n,k})x_{n,k}| \leq |E(x_{n,k})|x_{n,k}< \epsilon x_{n,k}$$

Also,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n x_{n,k} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{2k+2n}= \frac{1}{2}\ln(2) < 1$$

So that we can choose $N_2 \in \Bbb{N}$ s.t. for all $n \geq N_2$, $0< \sum_{k = 0}^n x_{n,k} < 1$.

Pick any $n \geq \max\{N_1, N_2\}$. We have

$$0 \leq \sum_{k = 0}^n |f(x_{n,k})-x_{n,k}|\leq \sum_{k = 0}^n \epsilon x_{n,k}= \epsilon \sum_{k = 0}^n  x_{n,k} < \epsilon$$

Comment: For a (much) shorter road, note that $$x-x^2\leqslant\log(1+x)\leqslant x$$ for every $x\geqslant0$ hence $$S_n-T_n\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac1{2k+2n}\right)\leqslant S_n$$ with $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k+2n}\to\frac12\log2$$ and $$T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(2k+2n)^2}\leqslant\frac{n}{4n^2}\to0$$

Comment: yes we can use limit x->0 ln(1+x)/x=1 =>ln(1+x)=x when x->0

Comment: and substitute x with 1/(2n+2k)

Comment: @IcaSandu yes you are right! $f(x)∼x$ is sufficient for our purpose since $\frac{1}{2n+2k}$ converges "uniformly" to $0$.